# How to access NES display register in Google's 8bit Map SDK?

Tags: google-maps

How do I access the display register of NES systems using the new Google's 8bit map SDK? Also, is it legal to make commercial  plugins for [Google's 8-bit map](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rznYifPHxDg) SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no new gimmick on Google 8-bit Map SDK. I think you have to create a new world map customly-designed as an 8-bit map, like sprites, characters, mobs, etc. Then you use Google Map SDK like you normally do. And whe you magnify a portion of your customized map, you can try adding some new sprites specifically in that portion of the map.

As for how Google displays the map in NES, let's just say they used a highly skilled Hollywood method of showing how it's done. When you look closely, you never see Google displaying the map on TV, you're just directly viewing it from a monitor of some sort.

I do not believe that there are commercial plugins for Google's 8-bit map SDK. Unless Google announced that it's available to the general public and claimed it as their own, I believe it's legal to make commercial plugins for that, but only when you are granted permission from Google themselves.

This question seems legit, just pretty weird when you phrase it like that.

Answer (score 1):

there you go: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/-t3YmEBs_Co